# How do I get the number of children in a protected Firebase collection?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have a protected firebase collection for users of my site, just an array of user objects. The permission rules for users allow an authenticated user to access only their user object in the list of users and no one else.

I'm trying to setup a simple way to get the count of all users in the collection with this permission scheme so that I can display a total user count on my site, however there doesn't seem to be a way to get a count of all users without getting a permission problem.

Any ideas about how to fix this?

I suppose I could store a count at a publicly readable firebase location that gets incremented and decremented whenever a user is added/removed, but I'd rather not store the data twice and worry about mismatches.

I suppose I could also have an authenticated watcher on my server that bypasses the permission requirement and sends to the client (either through firebase by writing to public location or exposed as an api) a user count.

Ideally I'd like to have everything client side at the moment, so please let me know if there's a simple permissions based solution to this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Data duplication is pretty much the norm in NoSQL, so storing a counter is perfectly reasonable. Check out the Firebase article on [denormalization](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html)

This pretty much sums up the approaches as I understand them.

**Using a counter**

It's fast and it's fairly simple, assuming you're using good DRY principles and centralizing all your manipulations of the records. Utilize a transaction to update the counter each time a record is added or removed:

```
function addUser(user) {
   // do your add stuff...
   updateCounter(1);
}

function removeUser(user) {
   // do your remove stuff...
   updateCounter(-1);
}

function updateCounter(amt) {
   userCounter.transaction(function(currentValue) {
      currentValue || (currentValue === 0); // can be null
      return currentValue + amt;
   });
}
```

**Separate public and secured data**

Store sensitive data (email addresses, things people can't see) in a private path, keep their public user data readable.

This prevents the need to synchronize a counter. It does mean, however, that clients must download the entire list of public users to create a count. So keep the public profiles small (a name, a timestamp, not much else) so it works into the tens of thousands without taking seconds.

```
"users": {
   ".read": true,
   "$user": {
       // don't try to put a ".read" here; it won't remove access
       // after the parent path allows it
   }
}

"users_secured": {
   "$user": {
       ".read": "auth.id === $user"
   }
}
```

**Utilize a server process**

Easy and painless; uber fast for clients, easily handles hundreds of thousands of profiles as long as they have a small footprint. Requires you to maintain something. [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com) and [Nodejitsu](http://www.nodejitsu.com) will host this for free until you have users coming out of your ears.

```
var Firebase = require('firebase');

var fb = new Firebase(process.env.FBURL);
fb.auth( process.env.SECRET, function() {
   fb.child('users').on('value', function(snap) {
      fb.child('user_counter').set( snap.numChildren() );
   });
}
```